# Bundle does not fully received

Tags: android, bundle, android-intent, parcelable

I am facing a problem with sending data through the bundle.

```
Intent toAudio = new Intent(TourDescription.this, Audio.class);
toAudio.putParcelableArrayListExtra("poi", arraypoi);
startActivity(toAudio);
```

here am sending `arraypoi` which is an ArrayList. This ArrayList contains a set of values.

And in the receiving class, I have like this

```
listOfPOI = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("poi");
Collections.sort(listOfPOI);
```

where `listOfPOI` is also an array list.

The problem am facing is, I am not able to receive values for 3 particular variables in `listOfPOI` (coming as `null`), rest all values are coming proper.

While sending the bundle, I mean in `arraypoi` also I am able to send all the values correctly but the problem is while receiving it.

Note: My class is implemented as `parcelable` only.

Any answer for this?

Comment: have to see the parcelable class code. Edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds in my point of view.

**First:**

You need to make `YourOwnArrayList` as subclass of `ArrayList<YourObject>` and `implements` `Parcelable`.
[Tutorial Here](http://www.anddev.org/simple_tutorial_passing_arraylist_across_activities-t9996.html)

**Second:**

pass your Object using `for()` loop. like this.

```
Intent toAudio = new Intent(TourDescription.this, Audio.class);
toAudio.putExtra("SIZE", arraypoi.size());
for(int i=0; i<arraypoi.size(); i++)
    toAudio.putExtra("POI"+i, arraypoi.get(i));
startActivity(toAudio);
```

and while getting in other class

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
int size=data.getInt("SIZE");
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    listOfPOI.add((YOUR_OBJECT) data.getParcelable("POI"+i));
```

`YOUR_OBJECT` is the class name of your `Object`.